# TFS locking sln whenever I "Get Latest"

Tags: tfs

Something odd has happened to TFS 
Using Visual studio 2015, whenever any developer does a "get latest", the .sln file is locked.

I did this just now and tried an undo changes, but I got [image: Undo Pending Changes]

Now I know that the vssscc is a TFS config file, and I'm not 100% sure it SHOULD be checked in to the repo.  But this all started happening recently, and I am at a loss.

Comment: Someone locked the file sln please check the output of your console in VS when getting the latest version

Answer (score 0):

> TFS locking sln whenever I “Get Latest”

Yes, we unlock other's changes with the tf undo command if you're the project administrator:

Check the blog: [Unlock the files checked out by other users](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tfssetup/2012/03/21/unlock-the-files-checked-out-by-other-users/)

For the second question, *I know that the vssscc is a TFS config file, and I'm not 100% sure it SHOULD be checked in to the repo*.

The `.vssscc` file is referred to as the solution hint file. It has entries to help keep the solution in sync with source control.

So, the `.vssscc` file should be added to source control, you should check it in.

Hope this helps.